# How to get Disconnect Event from BLE layer - Bluez/Linux

Tags: disconnect, bluez, hci, gatt

A previous question [How to get Disconnect Event from GATT Server on Bluez/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21673169/how-to-get-disconnect-event-from-gatt-server-on-bluez-linux) addresses the disconnect event for Bluez stack.

However since the disconnection detection is at the GATT layer it takes a while for the disconnection to be detected at the GATT Layer. Delayed disconnection detection would be an issue for many applications.

Bluez provides HCI API to connect/disconnect at BLE layer:

```
int hci_le_create_conn();
int hci_disconnect();
```

How does an application catch an HCI event indicating that a BLE connection made by hci_le_create_conn() is now disconnected.

Comment: Is there a sample code for  hci_le_create_conn() ?